# Different results with agregate and analytical with distinct functions

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I can't understand why there is the difference in results between two queries:

```
1) select distinct sum(lot.lot_size) over (partition by lot.detail_id) buying_size, lot.f_detail_id
   from buying
   join lot on lot.lot_id = buying.lot_id
   where exists (select 1
                 from selling s
                 join buying b on b.buying_id = s.buying_buying_id
                 where s.deal_id = 123456
                 and buying.deal_id = b.deal_id 
                 and s.selling_detailid = buying.buying_detailid)
    and buying.buying_status <> 'Canceled'
```

result:

```
    |buying_size|f_detail_id |
    |-----------|------------|
    |    105    |     1      |
    |    200    |     2      |
    |    75     |     3      |
    |    225    |     4      |
    |    300    |     5      |

2) select distinct *
   from (select sum(lot.lot_size) over (partition by lot.detail_id) buying_size, lot.f_detail_id
       from buying
       join lot on lot.lot_id = buying.lot_id
       where exists (select 1
                     from selling s
                     join buying b on b.buying_id = s.buying_buying_id
                     where s.deal_id = 123456
                     and buying.deal_id = b.deal_id 
                     and s.selling_detailid = buying.buying_detailid)
        and buying.buying_status <> 'Canceled')
```

result:

```
    |buying_size|f_detail_id |
    |-----------|------------|
    |    105    |     1      |
    |    200    |     2      |
    |    75     |     3      |
    |    225    |     4      |
    |    150    |     5      |
```

I know that this query might be written by another way with using GROUP BY but the main thing I'm interested in is why the result of analytical function depends on DISTINCT.

Comment: What is the result of the second query but without the distinct? Do you get 2 results for f_detail_id=5 both with a value of 150?

Comment: The second query only has one column.  It cannot be producing those results.

Comment: Rene, I get several results for each f_detail_id without the distinct.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, I have forgotten to fix it, thanks.